# How to Mask a String value into a series of _ _ _ _ _

Tags: java, encryption

How to encrypt a string value into a series of _ _ _ _

Example: A Tale of Two Cities -> _ ____ __ ___ ______

I'm working on this code and I'm stuck with the encryption part. Maybe you can help me with it. Thanks in advance

**Updated code:

```
public static String encryptTitle() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String underscoreLines = "";
    String title = getRandomTitle();

    String regex = "[^\\s-]";
    for (int i = 0; i < title.length(); i++) {
        underscoreLines = title.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "_");
    }
    return underscoreLines;
}
```

As you can see from the sample output below, the _ does not match the length and format of the movie title.

Output:
[image: Sample output]

Comment: That's not encryption, it's *masking*. Encryption can be reversed, but `_ ____ __ ___ ______` cannot be reversed, because many different texts fit those placeholders.

Comment: @Andreas Oh, yeah. That's what I wanted to do. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to make use of the RegEx [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))-method:

```java
String underscoreLines = title.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "_")
// [A-Za-z] -> matches every letter
// -> replaces every letter with "_"
```

Comment: I tried it but the title does not match the underscores it is returning

Comment: @Pledis Can you provide some examples? For instance example from question seems to be working fine. Demo: https://ideone.com/RIpdHm

Comment: I have updated the question with the code that I used and a sample output.

Comment: @Pledis looks like `getRandomTitle()` returns "Movie Title". Can you output `title` and `underscoreLines `? `System.out.println("Title: " + title ", Underscore-Lines: " + underscoreLines)`

Comment: It prints out another title instead. Ohh, I think I know where the problem lies. The (Movie Title : some title here) is invoked from the getRandomTitle() method in the main class and  another is invoked in the encryptTitle() method. It could be that when the program is ran, since it is a separate invocation two separates titles are being randomly selected. That must be the reason why the return string of encyptTitle is not matched with the title that is printing on the output terminal. Will try to improve it now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to replace all characters that are not a whitespace with `_`.

You could iterate every character of input and if its whitespace then add whitespace if not add `_`.

```
        String result = "";
        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == ' ') {
                result += c;
            } else {
                result += "_";
            }
        }
```

OR and better way is to use regex and it looks like

```
        String regex = "[^\\s-]";
        input = input.replaceAll(regex, "_");
```

Comment: I tried the second one but the underscores showing does not match with the text that is being stored in the title variable. Also tried the first one, it is the same but with lots of underscores this time.

Comment: Can you provide me with the input you were using for that?

Comment: Strings are immutable. `input.replaceAll(regex, "_");` will not *modify* `input` but will return *new* string with replaced values. You may want to reassign that result back to `input` like `input = input.replaceAll(...)`. Also ``\`` is special inside string literals (it can for instance be used to create `\t` `\n` `\uXXXX`). To produce ``\`` which can be passed to regex engine we need to escape it in string, so instead of ``\s`` we need to write it as ``\\s``.